# iOS - How to add custom view to table only if the user wants to pull to refresh?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview, pull-to-refresh

Hi I have the following code to add a custom pull to refresh view to my UITableView -

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < scrollView.contentSize.height && !CGSizeEqualToSize(scrollView.contentSize, CGSizeZero)) {
            [self addPullToRefreshView];
    }
}
```

This if statement gets executed even if I am not pulling to refresh, and just scrolling down or up in the table. Any thoughts on how to execute it only on pull to refresh?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what led you to this implementation, but typical behaviour for pull-to-refresh is to trigger it when you have scrolled up above a certain amount (let's say 21 points), so this code would seem more like it:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < -21) {
            [self addPullToRefreshView];
    }
}
```

Note: In your code, define a constant instead of using a "magic number" such as 21 above.

Comment: Even if I do that, if i scroll down the table and then back up, the scrollView.contentOffset.y falls below 21 even as I scroll back up without intending to pull to refresh. Any idea how I can get over that?

Comment: I guess what you describe shows that the behaviour you are trying to capture is more complex than just looking at scroll offset in scrollViewDidScroll. Thankfully iOS6+ includes a dedicated UIRefreshControl that you can use instead of writing your own: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRefreshControl_class/